# Calling handleClick before render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to call the handleClick(e) before render() so that the range value is ready for the Marker. It's pretty much first react app and it's the only small issue left. First time I click, range value is empty, then it's the previous value instead of latest.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css';
import {LocationIcon} from './LocationIcon';
import Distance from './Distance'
var range, dist;
const MyMarker = props => {

  const initMarker = ref => {
    if (ref) {
      ref.leafletElement.openPopup()
    }
  }

  return <Marker ref={initMarker} {...props}/>
}

class User2View extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      currentPos: null,
      range: 'k'};
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick(e){
    this.setState({ currentPos: e.latlng });
    localStorage.setItem('Poslat2', this.state.currentPos.lat);
    localStorage.setItem('Poslon2', this.state.currentPos.lng);
    const lat1 = localStorage.getItem('Poslat1');
    const lon1 = localStorage.getItem('Poslon1');
    const lat2 = localStorage.getItem('Poslat2');
    const lon2 = localStorage.getItem('Poslon2');
    dist = Distance(lat1, lon1, lat2, lon2);
    if (dist <= 1) {
      range = "User is in range"
    }
    else {
      range = "User is not in range"
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Map center={this.props.center} zoom={this.props.zoom} onClick={this.handleClick}>
          <TileLayer
              url='https://{s}.tile.osm.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png'
          />
          
          { this.state.currentPos && <MyMarker icon={LocationIcon}  position={this.state.currentPos}>
            <Popup position={this.state.currentPos}>
              <pre>{range}</pre>
            </Popup>
          </MyMarker>}
        </Map>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default User2View;
```

I had tried getDerivedStateFromProps and componentDidMount but nothing working..
Thank You

Comment: If possible in the future, try to reduce your code examples to the problematic and important pieces of your code while keeping the example reproducible.

Comment: Yeap :) You can read it at [mcve]. In addition you can read the [tour] and [ask]

Comment: Sure. I'll keep that in mind next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your range needs to be set to a certain value before the component mounts, that should go in the `constructor`. If it's okay for it to be set when the component mounts, you can put it in `componentDidMount`.

Here's some documentation to read up on lifecycle methods:

https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount

Comment: Okay this helped. Initialised a local state of range in constructor and then set it's state later when I got the value. Thank You